Windows API for reading laptop hinge position/angle
My laptop has a sensor that can detect how far the hinge is bent. This is because it can turn 360 degrees. The accelerometer is in the display, keeping the display up right and rotating the body past 180 degrees, it switches to tablet mode. This isn't done with classic magnets in the display and body and it's not using the accelerometer as I can read the accelerometer data to know it stays in place, the hinges themselves must know the angle at which they are bent. It also changes mode again when it's fully opened 360 degrees.
Software like Armoury Crate must be able to read this sensor's data to switch power state. Which API is used to accomplish this?
I tried HingeAngleSensor but that doesn't give me a sensor, this API must be for a different kind of sensor.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/sensor-orientation

sounds more like a switch to me, but maybe if you tell us about the model you've got, we can give more help

@Mahobo ASUS ROG Flow X16.
I have a driver GPIO driver for laptop/slate indicator.
Usually it is a switch, either it's a sensor that determines an angle or it's a switch with at least 3 states. Either way I want to read which state it's in or what angle
